# Github API based backend using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just created a Github API based backend, this api retrieves and stores information from the github users api

**app/Http/Controllers/GitController.php** ,I am using Requests, Actions and services

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Actions\CreateUserAction;
use App\Actions\SearchUserAction;
use App\Http\Requests\SearchUserRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class GitController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create users from Github users api.
     *     
     */
    public function index(CreateUserAction $createUserAction): void
    {
        $createUserAction->execute();        
    }

    /**
     * Search for users
     *     
     */
    public function search(SearchUserRequest $request, SearchUserAction $searchUserAction): JsonResponse
    {        
        $users = $searchUserAction->execute($request->username);
        return response()->json($users);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(User $user) : User
    {
        return $user;        

    }

}
```

**app/Http/Requests/SearchUserRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class SearchUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'nullable|string',
        ];
    }
}
```

**app/Actions/CreateUserAction.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Actions;

use App\Services\Github;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CreateUserAction{

    public $github;    

    public function __construct(Github $github)
    {
        $this->github = $github;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $users = $this->github->users();        

        $users = $this->createUsersArray($users);        
        
        DB::table('users')->insert($users);
    }

    public function createUsersArray($users)
    {        
     
        $users_array= [];        
        foreach ($users->collect() as $user) {

            $user_response = $this->github->user($user['url']);
            $user_ob = $user_response->collect();

            $users_array[] = [
                'username' => $user['login'],
                'email' => $user_ob['email'],
                'location' => $user_ob['location'],
                'join_date' => $user_ob['created_at'],
                'number_of_repositories' => $user_ob['public_repos'],
                'followers' => $user_ob['followers'],
                'following' => $user_ob['following'],
                'avatar_url' => $user_ob['avatar_url']
            ];
        }

        return $users_array;
    }    
}
```

**app/Services/Github.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class Github
{
    public function headers()
    {
        return  [
            'Accept' => 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . config('github.token')
        ];
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return Http::withHeaders($this->headers())->get(config('github.base_url') . '/users');
    }

    public function user(string $url)
    {
        return Http::withHeaders($this->headers())->get($url);
    }
   
}
```

**config/github.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'token' => env('GITHUB_TOKEN', null),
    'base_url' => env('GITHUB_BASE_URL', null),
];
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/collect-information', [GitController::class, 'index']);
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::get('/users', [GitController::class, 'search']);

Route::get('/users/{user}', [GitController::class, 'show']);
```

.env

```
GITHUB_TOKEN=ghp_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GITHUB_BASE_URL=https://api.github.com
```

is it correct the use of Actions, Service, docblocks, etc? what do you think, thanks